# Calling Map Function using Data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am Movielens Data to to do some analysis. So in u.item data is in this form.

```
 movie id | movie title | release date | video release date |
 IMDb URL | unknown | Action | Adventure | Animation |
 Children's | Comedy | Crime | Documentary | Drama | Fantasy |
 Film-Noir | Horror | Musical | Mystery | Romance | Sci-Fi |
 Thriller | War | Western |

1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2|GoldenEye (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995)|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
3|Four Rooms (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Four%20Rooms%20(1995)|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
```

As you can see in this Data from 5th to 23rd columns we have genre in the form of 0 and 1. So I am trying to convert these genre from 0,1 to number like

```
unknown - 0
Action - 1
etc
```

Sow what i have done so far

```
def refineMovieDF(row):
genre=[]
movieData =row.split("|")
for i in range(len(movieData[5,25])):
    if movieData[i] ==1:
        genre.append(i)
return Row(MovieId = movieData[0],Genre=genre)
movieDF = spark.read.load("ml-100k/u.item",format="csv",inferSchema=True, header=False)

movieRefined = movieDF.rdd.map(refineMovieDF).toDF().collect()
```

I am getting error in split

```
 Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 253, in main
process()
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in process
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 379, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1352, in takeUpToNumLeft
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 55, in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cloudera/workspace/MovielensAnalysis.py", line 13, in refineMovieDF
movieData =row.split("|")
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1561, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: split
```

Is this method correct ?

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: What is the data type of `row` ? Add a print to show it: `print(type(row))`

Comment: <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>

Comment: Why do you  think this class has the method `split` ? See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.Row-class.html . `Row` is kind of tuple so you can access its attributes by index. Example: `row[0]`

Comment: As @balderman mentioned there's no `split` method on `Row` object. What output do you expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to combine all the `0`s and `1`s from column `unknown` to the last column into one array for each row. Then create a new array that only has the indexes of all the `1`s. If so, here's what I would do.
I'll use `functions.array` to combine all the `0`s and `1`s first:

```
cols = movieDF.columns
movieDF = movieDF.withColumn("genre", F.array(cols[5:]))
movieDF = movieDF.select(['movie id', 'movie title', 'genre'])
movieDF.show()
```

Here's the output:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------------------+
|movie id|      movie title|               genre|
+--------+-----------------+--------------------+
|       1| Toy Story (1995)|[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1...|
|       2| GoldenEye (1995)|[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0...|
|       3|Four Rooms (1995)|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...|
+--------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Then I'll use `udf` to get the indexes of all the `1`s:

```
def get_index_of_one(g):
    return [idx for idx, k in enumerate(g) if k == 1]

myudf = F.udf(lambda g: get_index_of_one(g), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
movieDF = movieDF.withColumn('genre2', myudf('genre'))
movieDF.show()
```

Here's the final output:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+
|movie id|      movie title|               genre|    genre2|
+--------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+
|       1| Toy Story (1995)|[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1...| [3, 4, 5]|
|       2| GoldenEye (1995)|[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0...|[1, 2, 16]|
|       3|Four Rooms (1995)|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...|      [16]|
+--------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Hope that's what you are looking for.